# When extending a contract how to call the external constructor and pass parameters?

Tags: openzeppelin, erc-721, constructor

I have the following contract

```
import "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol";

contract Contract is ERC721Token {
    function Contract(string _name, string _symbol) public { 
        name_ = _name; // This does not work because name_ is internal
        symbol_ = _symbol; // This does not work because symbol_ is internal
    }
}
```

The ERC721Token contract has a **name_** variable that is set in the **constructor**, how do call this constructor or set the var from this contract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the super constructor as part of your declaration:

```
constructor(string _name, string _symbol) ERC721Token(_name, _symbol) public {    
     // Any additional constructor code you need
}
```

Comment: This got me one step further, the issue I have now is that I get the error that ERC721Token does not expect any parameters.. Any clue?

Comment: Hmm. At least the current [master](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol#L40) does expect the parameters. Check your import path and make sure the file is present and contains the correct code.